# Suggestion needed for learning Java

Tags: java

I need some advice in learning Java and getting Java certification. My target is to get Certified. I am acquainted with C, C++, feel quite okay with the topics.

As I already mentioned that I need some suggestions about, how to start Java and where to start. Please help me in this regard.

I already downloaded,

1. SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6.pdf
2. Osborne - The Complete Reference Java 2 (5th Edition).pdf
3. And some free Java tutorials, from sun website and other places

So, please suggest me what more I could do, and where else I need to look. Is there any better resource for Java Beginners? I really need to learn it fast. And yes, I am dedicated with all my efforts.

It would be nice if someone can pass me links to some online Java compilers.

Comment: Do you mean java *certification* ?

Comment: @USER: I have taken the liberty of editing your post. I hope you wouldn't mind that. Feel free to revert back, if you think some significant bits of your question are lost.

Comment: online java compilers..is there..or not..iam searcing ..but unable to found it.

Comment: @USER: Yes there is. I forgot that to add in my answer. See the answer now, I've added that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Head First Java](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=nzhxR1spWEYC&dq=head+first+java&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=cXw7TJfvFs-rcdKorfsO&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a good book for beginners.

See the [Oracle Java Tutorials section](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) on Getting Started.

Also check out the question that has been previously asked

[Best Java book you have read so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far)

[Java Ranch](http://www.javaranch.com/) is a good website for Java forums and FAQs

The book [Java Language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/jTOC.doc.html) is also available online.

My suggestion is that you should get a hard copy of Head First Java.
It is the best book for beginners.

**Java Compilers**

1. [Download JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. IF you want to use an IDE then [Download Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
3. Want to use an online compiler? Use [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: Effective Java or Practical Java is also a must have for real life java exp.

Comment: @zengr : I agree but Effective Java is not for beginners right?

Comment: By my personal experience, dont go with that mind set, if you know very basics of programming, then java is very easy to understand and you should read effective java to understand the read java. It's a steep learning curve initially but highly rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from reading books and doing multiple choice question tutorials the best way to learn something is to actually use it. **I suggest you start doing some actual programming in Java.** Think of a couple of smallish apps and just start trying to use what you have learned studying.

Answer (score 0):

> Can u able to suggest me some sites to
>   learn a bit easily...a tutorials. But
>   i need to learn with in short time.Iam
>   keeping my full efforts for this to
>   achieve.

Aside the Java Standard Tutorials, referred by @org.life.java, if you need to learn Java EE (Servlets, JSP, EJBs, SOAP, etc, etc, etc), con can check the [Java Blue Prints](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-136701.html), with lot of code examples.

> Provide me some links ---> online free
>   compilers for java

You can download the [last JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) from Oracle page for free. With the JDK you'll be able to compile.

Anyway, you better download a IDE to start programming. The easiest to learn is [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/). Other option, with more functionality and more customizable is [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Comment: for JEE I would suggest HeadFirst

Comment: @org.life.java: I haven't read it. I'll check it for some of my "newby" coworkers. Thanks for the point

Answer (score 0):

Look for some books, they are really helpfull (and java doc of course!):
[Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=bks%3A1&tbo=1&q=java&btnG=Search+Books)


I have read (spanish): Estructura de Datos en Java from Mark Allen Weiss, it is a GOOD beginning...

If you think you are **OK** with C and C++ then you are **OK** with Java, its easier to learn I think, good luck with that...

and of course search for JAVA API 1.6 on GOOGLE (i cant post more links sorry)